# SocketException proper handling in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, vb6

I'm currently writing a code in `C#` and it needs to communicate with a program written in `VB6` through sockets. `<br/>`
When the `VB6` program is not running, my C# program throws a SocketException. 
What I did was catch the exception but I noticed that it will keep throwing that exception until the `VB6` program runs again.`<br/><br/>`
The ReceiveFrom(...) method is in an infinite loop so when the VB6 program runs again, it can receive data.`<br/><br/>`
I wonder if there's a better way to handle this.
the C# code looks like this...

```
internal class SocketConnection : Connection
{
    private Socket socket;
    private EndPoint localEndPoint;
    private IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint;

    internal SocketConnection(int localPortNumber, IPAddress remoteIPAddress, int remotePortNumber)
    {
        IPEndPoint localIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(
            GetLocalIPAddress(),
            localPortNumber);

        socket = new Socket(
            localIPEndPoint.Address.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Dgram,
            ProtocolType.Udp);

        socket.Bind(localIPEndPoint);

        localEndPoint = (EndPoint)localIPEndPoint;
        Thread receiver = new Thread(() => Receive());
        receiver.Start();

        remoteIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(remoteIPAddress, remotePortNumber);
    }

    private void Receive()
    {
        byte[] msg = new Byte[256];
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                socket.ReceiveFrom(msg, ref localEndPoint);
                buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg).TrimEnd('\0');
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                buffer = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
    private IPAddress GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
    }

    protected override void Interrogate(string message)
    {
        socket.SendTo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message), remoteIPEndPoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really. As long as the exception is handled it's generally fine. You could change the behaviour such that the process does a `Thread.Sleep(x)` for some amount of time when that error happens, instead of constantly having the loop try to connect and throw an error. This depends on the general behaviour of these two applications, though, maybe you need very rapid checking, maybe if the VB app isn't running you can sleep the C# application for a while and then check again. It's up to you but in general handled socket errors aren't a huge deal, though it may be ideal to not throw constantly.

Comment: +1 on the Thread.Sleep(x) in the catch block...
though I wonder if there's a way to refactor how the socket listens to the data. like with System.IO.Ports, there is a DataReceived event so I don't need to constantly loop for a Read method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling `ReceiveFrom` you should check that there is something to read in the socket :

```
                int available = socket.Available;
                if (available > 0)
                {
                    socket.ReceiveFrom(msg, 0, Math.Min(msg.Length, available), SocketFlags.None, ref localEndPoint);
                    buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg).TrimEnd('\0');
                }
```

Comment: I tried this and adjusted the condition to available > 1.. since the available property can be 0 or 1 even when there is no data from the network..

Comment: This also eliminates the exception thrown by the socket which is nice. Then I added a Thread.Sleep on the else block. :)